# Terrible MongoCursor::getNext performance on a VPS

Tags: php, performance, mongodb

I was trying to figure out why the site hosted on a VPS with 2GB RAM started showing pages in ~2 seconds while on localhost it only takes about 200ms at worst. I want to note that IIRC, it didn't happen in the past, and there is no difference in load or visitor count. Top shows 0% CPU usage most of the time, 77M RAM free, 4M swap used.

I have profiled a slow request and discovered that 87% of the time is spent calling `MongoCursor::getNext`. The mongodump of the used DB is 800MB, so the memory shouldn't be a problem. The OS is 64bit Ubuntu 11.

What steps do I take to fix this problem?

Comment: I think the manual talks about steps you can take for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be caused by old mongo version - on the VPS it was 1.8.* and on my local box - 2.0.4. After I upgraded mongo and `mongorestore`d the data I had to run `db.repairDatabase()` since some data wasn't fetching with `error: { "$err" : "assertion db/key.cpp:409" }`. Now everything is back to normal.